# Objective-C connect to odoo

Tags: objective-c, odoo, xml-rpc

I'am trying to connect to odoo with objective-c.I used the xmlrpc api provided by odoo and try to adapt their example (python,java...) with objective-c. I succeed in extracting some data, but in some cases (hr_holidays) it throw an error (No value found for res.users('1',).groups_id). the weird thing is that i can extract from this model with python.
Is anyone have experiences with this kind of problem.
Thanks.
Codes:

```
NSArray *leaves = [NSArray array];
XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.host, @"object"]]];

NSArray *params = @[db,@"1",self.password,@"hr.holidays",@"search",@[@[@[@"id",@"!=",@"0"]]]];

[request setMethod:@"execute_kw" withParameters: params];

XMLRPCResponse *nodeSaveResponse = [XMLRPCConnection sendSynchronousXMLRPCRequest:request error:nil];
NSString* result = [nodeSaveResponse body];
NSLog(@"%@",result);

if ([nodeSaveResponse faultCode]==0) {
    NSDictionary *xmlDoc = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithXMLString:result];
    NSLog(@"%@",xmlDoc);
}else{
    NSString* error = @"error";
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
```

The Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
 <methodResponse>
 <fault>
 <value><struct>
 <member>
 <name>faultCode</name>
 <value><int>2</int></value>
 </member>
 <member>
 <name>faultString</name>
 <value><string>No value found for res.users('1',).groups_id</string>   </value>
 </member>
 </struct></value>
 </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Comment: Hi I'm trying to implement xmlrpc too in swift. May I know what library did you use and how to request the data in xmlrpc/common

Comment: it's a late response for a late reaction :). I afraid i can't help you, because it was an old project and i was using objective-c. sorry :(